# Neighbourhood properties topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm going through the properties of the neighbourhood system. I'm stuck on the last one which states.

> Let $x \in X$ then the neighbourhood system has the following properties.
>
> property 1
>
> property 2...
>
> property 4: if $U\in U_x$ then there is $V \in U_x$ s.t $U \in U_y$ for all $y \in V$
>
> Where $U_x = \{U \subset X: U \text{ neighbour of } x \in X \}$

Can someone provide me with a hint where to start, if can get my thinking in the right direction, I want to try to finish the proof myself.

Comment: What is the interior of $U$?

Comment: Perhaps the set $M$ that satiesfies  $M \in T, \ x \in M$ and $M \subset U$, making $U$ a neighbourhood of $x$ ? @DanielFischer

Comment: The comment was intended as a hint where to start.

Comment: Why did "you" downvote?

Comment: Are you asking a general "you", or do you think I downvoted? In the former case, don't expect an answer, it's unlikely the downvoter will return to this question.

Comment: Im asking in general. And I dont understand the purpose of downvoting without making a comment @DanielFischer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $U\in U_x$.

$U\in U_x \implies$

$\exists O$ open $: x\in O \subset U$.

take now $y\in O$.

$y\in O \implies$

$y \in O \subset U \implies$

$U\in U_y$.

the $V$, we are looking for is $O$.